# Number the conjugacy classes of a group of odd order is also is odd.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ a group of odd order. Show that the number the conjugacy classes is also is odd.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: The size of any orbit under the action of conjugation divides the order of $G$ by the orbit stabilizer theorem, so the size of every conjugacy class (orbit) is odd. Since the orbits (conjugacy classes) partition $G$, what happens if there are an even number of conjugacy classes?