# Number of conjugacy classes of odd order in a group of even order is odd

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

The following is a problem from a practice exam:

> Suppose $G$ is a group of finite, even order. Prove that the number of conjugacy classes in $G$ with odd order is odd.

This can't be right, can it? If $G$ is abelian of order $2n$, then there are $2n$ conjugacy classes of order $1$. Am I misinterpreting this question?

I think of a conjugacy class as the set of elements conjugate to some element $x\in G$.
Could it also be taken the mean the class $H^G$ of conjugates of a subgroup? I would have phrased that as the conjugacy classes in the set $X=\{H\mid H\leq G\}$.

Even so, I think this still couldn't be right, because if $G$ is a p-group, then $X=\{\{1\},G\setminus\{1\}\}$, so there are two classes of odd order.

So $\mathbb{Z}_2$ would be a counterexample to both supposed propositions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a consequence of the fact that the identity is its own conjugacy class.  The conjugacy classes partition the group,  so the only way to get a group of even order is if there's an odd number of conjugacy classes of odd order, other than that of the identity.

Answer (score 1):

You have mixed up two different statements. The first sentence has nothing to do with the second:

[Prove that the number of conjugacy classes in $G$ with odd order is odd.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1477197/number-the-conjugacy-classes-of-a-group-of-odd-order-is-also-is-odd)

Here "order" means the order of $G$. So the second sentence is correct. The first sentence needs to be deleted.

Comment: I see. So,
If $|G|$ is odd, then since the order of each conjugacy class divides $|G|$, every conjugacy class must have odd order. And there must be an odd number of them since, if not, $|G|$ would be even.

If $|G|$ is even, then if we remove all the elements in conjugacy classes of even order, we must have an odd number of non-identity conjugacy classes of odd order, so there must also overall be an even number of conjugacy classes of odd order (including $\{1\}$).